# How can I update iOS apps that I own but were installed from a different account?

Tags: ios, itunes, applications

I used to have access to two different app store accounts. My own, personal one and another that belonged to a client I worked with. I had to use that client's account a lot and AFAIK you can't configure an iOS device to remember multiple logins, so I would often install apps I already owned from their account.

I no longer work with that client and, at some point, they changed their password. Now, when I try and update those apps, it challenges me for a password. I could understand this if these were apps I don't have on my own account, but I do.

Deleting and re-installing these apps fixes the problem. But there are some apps I'd prefer not to delete because I want to keep local content.

I'm presuming I might be able to get round this by hooking up my iOS devices to my PC and backing them up with iTunes. Then deleting and reinstalling the apps. However, I'm not sure this will work. I also hate iTunes with a vengeance and would prefer not to use it if at all possible.

Will this work if I try it? Or is there any other way I can get my apps to update?

Comment: Your apps on a third party account = not your apps.

Comment: @JaimeSantaCruz Good spot, thanks. Question not an exact duplicate, but the answers do appear very relevant.

Comment: No problem, searched a lot to find the right words and then that question popped up on Google. We see a lot of this here in different flavors. Maybe a non Apple backup explorer might help save some work in the migration.